# Stretch container to bottom but allow it to extend if more content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for a better to a solution to the problem of not having enough content to fill the screen.

Usually, if you want to fill the screen you either make the HTML, body heights 100% and then your container 100% or just use 100vh like in my JSFiddle below.

The problem is if the content does eventually stretch past 100% height of the screen it gets cut off.

I was wondering if there was a way (maybe with flexbox) where you could have 100% height but also if the content goes past 100% the container expands in size.

```css
html, body
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content
{
  background: grey;
  /* height: 100vh; - this works but if content goes past 100vh it gets cut off */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <span>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container around the `content` to which you apply `100vh` and `display: flex`and now the `content` can be made a *column* `flexbox` - see demo below and [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0x9z1km/1/):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the **`overflow: auto;`** in your `.content` div

[Your Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/31bmgdxr/1/)

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background: grey;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Good solution, however you get a scrollbar which isn't great ui.

Comment: If the content extends div height scroll would definitely appear no matter how you do it :)

Comment: Hi Nikhil, if you look at the flexbox solution above it works without scrollbar.

Thanks for your solution aswell it's helpful.